# Is Grand Theft Auto IV - Episodes from Liberty City different from GTA IV?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

Is Grand Theft Auto IV - Episodes from Liberty City different from GTA IV or is it GTA IV + Ballad of Gay Tony + Lost & Damned?

Are the expansion packs separate from the main game?

Direct2Drive tells me Episodes from Liberty City is 16GB, while GTA IV is 14GB so was curious if the two are separate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is different.

Episodes from Liberty City only contains the expansions Ballad of Gay Tony + Lost & Damned. It does not contain the storyline from the original GTA IV. I would assume the size is so large because it includes most everything from the original game. The Xbox 360 expansions both weigh in at 2GB+ by themselves. The expansions make use of most of the entire city and have all the same vehicles, guns plus more.

Comment: so do I need to download both or just Episodes from Liberty City ?

Comment: @Sathya: If you want to play the original game and both expansions, yes you need both. You can buy the original without expansions and play that, you can buy the expansions separately from the original and just play them, or you can buy both and get the whole experience.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is,

It is GTA IV + Ballad of Gay Tony + Lost & Damned, hope this helps, by the way, I don't know the answer to your second question, sorry!